# She certainly has gone up or she has certainly gone up

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, word-order

She (**certainly has** or **has certainly**) gone up in my estimation since she told the manager what she thought of him.

Should *'certainly'* be used before or after **'has'**?

Comment: In that instance, like in many similar ones, it doesn't matter, IMHO.

Comment: These words can be arranged variously - *Certainly, she has gone up*, *She has certainly gone up [since]*, *She certainly has gone up [since]*

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter. The meaning doesn't change. Certainly is a substitution for *'Definitely'*. Alternatively,

1. > **She definitely has gone up..**
2. > **She has definitely gone up..**

In both these sentences, your 'estimation' of the subject has gone up and you're sure about that. Either of these sentences convey the same meaning.

Comment: I was given this sentence in an exam with the question, spot the error in the sentence and the error was in these words only "has certainly or certainly has".